# Android: Launch app on notification

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to get my app to start every time a user receives a notification from any anything on the device, is this actually possible? I've looked around quite alot but I can find anything, thanks!

Comment: You want to takeover the control of the phone when any activity/servic etc. makes an Notification?
No this isn't possible of cause.

Comment: Anyways, this is not the expected behavior that may mislead your users, try to avoid such things.

Comment: I don't actually want to start an app, I just want a service to run for a few minutes each time a notification is received.

Answer (score 0):

of corse it is possible. you can use PackageManagerInfo to get you lauch Activity and by Brodcast Receiver you can start your application